# Memory issue after ST_MakeValid()

Tags: postgis, postgresql

After running a ST_MakeValid() on a table with about ~400k records, I receive the following error:

```
update "parcel15B"
set geom = ST_MakeValid(geom)

ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16390/655718": wrote only 4096 of 8192 bytes at block 95300
    HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

I have run this query before on larger tables with no problems.  How should one check in which directory to free up space or is there another way to rewrite the same query which would use up less space?

Comment: That error message refers to the Postgres data file directory, which will be wherever your data_dir directory is. You can usually find this either  in postgresql.conf or in an init.d script on some *nix al flavours. This is also where your transaction log resides, and for ACID and MVCC reasons, you will need space to write out the results of ST_MakeValid before it is committed. So, if you have no option to make more space, you will have to do the query in batches.

Comment: This is **not** a "memory" issue. It's a disk I/O issue.